# Shortcut in intelliJ to jump to corresponding method

Tags: intellij-idea

On windows, I know that we can search for all the methods in the current class by using `Ctrl+F12`.

Suppose, that I am in the class Car.java
and there we have a method called `accelerate()`;

The method is really long and now I did some modifications at the end of this method. How can I jump back to the place where the method `accelerate()` starts?

I used `Ctrl+U` but that just does not do anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this page from IntelliJ's manual: [Method navigation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#method_navigation)

It's Alt+Up or Alt+Down